# Редактирование embed по нажатию кнопки

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

Пытаюсь повторить функцию, в которой по нажатию кнопки "голос пользователя" добавляется в определённый столбец Embed. (См. скрины 1 и 2)

[image: введите сюда описание изображения][image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
@bot.slash_command(description="Создание голосования")
async def voting(inter, title: str, description: str, vote_limit: int = 1, mention_family: str = mention_family):

    emb = disnake.Embed(title=title, description=description, colour=disnake.Color.purple())
    emb.add_field(name="<:checkmark:905943731067305996> Accepted", value="-", inline=True)
    emb.add_field(name="<:deletesign:905943741775368272> Declined", value="-", inline=True)
    emb.add_field(name="❔ Tentative", value="-", inline=True)

    buttons = disnake.ui.View()
    buttons.add_item(disnake.ui.Button(style=disnake.ButtonStyle.secondary, custom_id="checkmark", emoji="<:checkmark:905943731067305996>"))
    buttons.add_item(disnake.ui.Button(style=disnake.ButtonStyle.secondary, custom_id="deletesign", emoji="<:deletesign:905943741775368272>"))
    buttons.add_item(disnake.ui.Button(style=disnake.ButtonStyle.secondary, custom_id="undecided", emoji="❔"))

    content = "<@&904071673429495830>" if mention_family == "Тегнуть" else None

    await inter.send(content=content, embed=emb, allowed_mentions=disnake.AllowedMentions(roles=True), view=buttons)

@bot.event
async def on_button_click(inter: disnake.MessageInteraction):
    global good, bad, question
    user = inter.author.nick.split()[0] if inter.author.nick is not None else inter.author.name
    
    if inter.component.custom_id == "checkmark":
        good.append(user)
        emb.set_field_at(index=0, name="<:checkmark:905943731067305996> Accepted", value="\n".join(good))
    elif inter.component.custom_id == "deletesign":
        bad.append(user)
        emb.set_field_at(index=1, name="<:deletesign:905943741775368272> Declined", value="\n".join(bad))
    elif inter.component.custom_id == "undecided":
        question.append(user)
        emb.set_field_at(index=2, name="❔ Tentative", value="\n".join(question))
```

В on_button_click пытаюсь изменить определённый field, но не могу это сделать т.к. emb локальная переменная. Т.е. мне остаётся написать код для изменения значения, всё остальное сделано

Answer (score 0):

[Официальная документация](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html?highlight=edit#discord.Message.edit).

Первым делом вам надо получить сообщение по его ID

```py
msg = await ctx.fetch_message(msgID)
```

Дальше просто редактируете сообщение с помощью метода edit

```py
await msg.edit(embed=embed2)
```